# Table View Cell not displaying in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uitableview

I just started to learn IOS programming. Apologize in advance if this question is too entry level.

Using storyboard drag and drop, I simply created a view controller -> table view -> and then table view cell.

I am not sure why my table cell is not showing in the simulator. It is showing in the storyboard.

Since I can't post image (too new)
My simulator looks like this. Everything below is in a table view

"Text" (on the top),
Red colored section for table cell view (in the middle),
"Text2" (at the bottom)

When I run the simulator, I am seeing
"Text" (on the top),
"Text2" (at the bottom)

The Red colored section(table view cell) disappeared.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add code please? Are you using static or dynamic table view?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is dynamic Prototypes. Sorry, still trying to get used to Xcode. Where do I get the reverent source code for these table/views? Do I highlight the table view (or table view cell) and go to assistant editor? Looking at assistant editor, not sure it has what I need. I am more used to double click on visual studio.  Thanks!

Comment: <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill"reuseIdentifier="NewsFeed" id="7Jc-Xn-9sO"><rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/><autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/><tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="7Jc-Xn-9sO" id="tf9-Lf-8ll"><autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/><color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92" green="0.41" blue="1" alpha="1"/></tableViewCellContentView><color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.167" blue="0.177" alpha="1"/></tableViewCell>

Comment: Since this sounds like a beginning project and you can't add images, might help for you just to dump it on a github repo so someone can take a quick peek at your storyboard.

Comment: you should read this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702 :)

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you have assigned the dataSource and delegate attributes to self.

```
myTableView.dataSource = self
myTableView.delegate = self
```

and also called methods :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```